# Python error in polygon to raster conversion?

Tags: arcpy, raster, polygon, error-000800

I want to convert polygon to raster. I converted the dbf file ( "cntymam") to table view to make use in the conversion. I am getting a error that the parameters are not called and also with the grid name. I am not able figure out the error.

**Errors**

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000161: The length of the grid name must not exceed 13 characters
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of CELL_CENTER | MAXIMUM_AREA | MAXIMUM_COMBINED_AREA.
Failed to execute (PolygonToRaster).
```

**Script**

```
# Make layer and table view

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FLcounties, "flcnties")
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(cntymam2, "cntymam")

j=0

for species in mamList:
    if j < 10 :
        species_str = str(species)

        # polygon to raster 

        mamcnty_out = output_workSpace + "cnty_" + species_str

        Value_field = "cntymam2." + species_str

        print species_str, mamcnty_out, Value_field

        arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion("flcnties",Value_field, mamcnty_out, "CELL_CENTRE", "NONE", "90")

        print j
        j= j + 1
```

Comment: Hi Mukhtar, I edited you question a little so that the code was formatted correctly.  To do that in the future, just insert 4 spaces in the front of any lines that you want to show as code.  I don't have experience with RasterToPolygon, but I can tell you that the second error would be solved by changing `"CELL_CENTRE"` in your code to `"CELL_CENTER"`.

Comment: Couple of things. First, set your workspace separately using env.workspace rather than concatenating it as part of mamcnty_out. Second, make sure that your grid name cannot exceed 13 characters - possibly by truncating it before your PolygonToRaster_conversion. See also http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000030000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two fixes:

*For the first error:*

> ERROR 000161: The length of the grid name must not exceed 13
>   characters

Convert your output to tiff format, which does not have the character length limitations that the Esri grid raster format does.

```
mamcnty_out = os.path.join(output_workSpace, "cnty_" + species_str + ".tif")
```

*For the second error:*

> ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of CELL_CENTER | MAXIMUM_AREA
>   | MAXIMUM_COMBINED_AREA. Failed to execute (PolygonToRaster).

You spelled "CELL_CENTER" wrong

```
arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion("flcnties",Value_field, mamcnty_out, "CELL_CENTER", "NONE", "90")
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron. TIFF file format is the right way for this task.I appreciate your efforts to help out me.